# How to purge pooled objects?

Tags: castle-windsor

Suppose objects creation rely on some configuration that is rarely, but changed sometimes. It seems logical to pool them. But when configuration changed - I want them to be recreated by the container, i.e. I need to throw out existing ones. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing specifically for this scenario is built in, but it could be doable.

A lot depends on your application, and how those objects are being used. Perhaps a proxy with swappable target would be a good fit. Perhaps not.

A lot would depend on the way and frequency of how those objects are being used.

Comment: These are WCF services, so they're already behind proxies at least twice already :)
And user could change endpoint. I want it to go transparently for proxy consumers.